# Complex Tensors and Metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation, mathematics

> It has been given that in 2-dimensions, consider the metric: $$\ ds^2 = e^{\phi(z,\overline z)}dzd\overline z .$$
> Show that $$\ t_{z...z;z} = (\partial_{z} - n\partial_{z} \phi)t_{z....} .$$

I can't seem to wrap my head around this problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two hints for you to do it yourself:

1. You do not need anything fancy here. Recall what is the formula for the covariant derivative in local coordinates in terms of the connection coefficients: $$\nabla_A t_{B_1\cdots B_N}=\partial_A t_{B_1\cdots B_N}-\Gamma_{AB_1}^{C_1}t_{C_1 B_2\cdots B_N}-\cdots -\Gamma_{AB_N}^{C_N}t_{B_1\cdots B_{N-1}C_N}\tag{1}$$
2. Observe that you don't really need to compute all the Christoffel symbols. Figure out the ones you need after using (1) and then recall how they are related to the metric $$\Gamma_{AB}^C=\dfrac{1}{2}g^{CD}(\partial_A g_{DB}+\partial_B g_{AD}-\partial_D g_{AB})\tag{2}.$$

   This will turn out to be a quick computation since you don't even need all of them and since the metric is pretty simple. Nevertheless, computing all of them is a good exercise and you should carry it out.